# Incorrect SQL syntax occurs

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am, for the most part, just importing values into a table on MySQL. The following code gets a SQL syntax error:

```
        grossProfit = Double.parseDouble(salesText.getText())-Double.parseDouble(cogsText.getText());
        totalExpenses = Double.parseDouble(ExSalesText.getText())+Double.parseDouble(GaExText.getText())+Double.parseDouble(otherExText.getText());
        profit = grossProfit-totalExpenses;

        Sql = "update budgetreport" +
                " set sales=?"+
                ", cogs=?"+
                ", gross_profit=?"+
                ", sales_ex=?"+
                ",  g&a_ex=?"+
                ", other_ex=?"+
                ", total_ex=?"+
                ", profit=?"+
                " where quarter=?";
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
            statement.setString(1, salesText.getText());
            statement.setString(2, cogsText.getText());
            statement.setDouble(3, grossProfit);
            statement.setString(4, ExSalesText.getText());
            statement.setString(5, GaExText.getText());
            statement.setString(6, otherExText.getText());
            statement.setDouble(7, totalExpenses);
            statement.setDouble(8, profit);
            statement.setInt(9, qTracker);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It worked before, when I only had 2 input variables in the SQL code. How do I make this work?

Edit: Error(Just a SQL syntax error I believe)

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&a_ex='1', other_ex='1', total_ex=3.0, profit=3.0, where quarter=2' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
at myProjects.budgetReport.lambda$2(budgetReport.java:180)
at myProjects.budgetReport$$Lambda$15/1910163204.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please post the error log too

Comment: exception trace will help you and others

Comment: Do you really have a column named "g&a_ex"?

Comment: g&a_ex=?" r sure u have this column?

Comment: Is there a problem with the `&` character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g&a_ex` does not look like a valid column name. Most likely a typo

**EDIT**:
Thanks to Jason W for mentioning that actually & is allowed in mysql identifiers provided escaped with backtick `

Comment: This was the problem. It was not a typo, I meant to put it there, but of coarse either the conenctorj or MySQL does not allow it. Thank you.

Comment: Ampersand is allowed, but backtick (`) is required to escape the name

Comment: @WyattLowery You can always accept an answer if it helped. Accepting an answer helps others facing the same challenge. Accepting an answer is simple by clicking on the tick mark left to the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Check your query. It should be like

```
Sql = "update table budgetreport" +
            " set sales=?"+
            ", cogs=?"+
            ", gross_profit=?"+
            ", sales_ex=?"+
            ",  g&a_ex=?"+
            ", other_ex=?"+
            ", total_ex=?"+
            ", profit=?"+
            " where quarter=?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your table definition or benfit of error log, I assume the syntax error is one of your table names, `g&a_ex`. Perhaps this should be verified as the correct table name and corrected or escaped appropriately. To escape the table name, use the reverse single quote (`) around the column name.